# Possible ways of using Manual of Iron Golem, as a martial class?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Is there a way to use a manual of iron golem as a martial class? I have some theories, but is it possible?

THEORY 1: True polymorph into a creature with 2 5th level spell slots and spend the downtime and gold while in that form. Get dispelled after.

THEORY 2: Simulacrum a PC with 2 5th level spell and use that as a way to use the manual.

Comment: Is the question "how can I make it possible for me, a martial class, to use this Manual?" -- or is it "what are some ways I can use it, presuming I already can use it?". (The second one's off topic, but I can't tell clearly.) Could you tell us more about your character's build?